# POST-request from AngularJS to Laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I'm trying to send a POST-request from my AngularJS-app to an independent Laravel backend (on localhost), but can't figure out the X-CSRF-TOKEN stuff. At least I think that's the problem.

I'm always recieving this error in console:

```
POST http://localhost/public/drinks 419 (unknown status)
```

I've added this to index.html in my AngularJS app:

```
<script>angular.module("myCaffeineIntake").constant("CSRF_TOKEN", '{{ csrf_token() }}');</script>
```

And here is the code from my controller:

```
$scope.answer = function(newdrink, CSRF_TOKEN) {
     newdrink._token = CSRF_TOKEN;
     newdrink._method = "post";

     $http({
         method : "POST",
         url : "http://localhost/public/drinks",
         data : newdrink
     }).then(function mySuccess(response) {

     }, function myError(response) {
         console.log("error");
     }
 );
```

And my Laravel-controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $drink = new Drink;
    $this->validate(request(),[
        'Name' => 'required',
        'Size' => 'required',
        'Caffeine' => 'required',
        'Url' => 'required'
    ]);

    Drink::create([
        'Name' => request('Name'),
        'Size' =>  request('Size'),
        'Caffeine' => request('Caffeine'),
        'Amount' => 0,
        'Url' => request('Url'),
        'created_at' => time(),
        'updated_at' => time(),     
    ]);
}
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Is there any way you can check from the log if the csrf_token actually exists? There may be few reasons this is happening, and one of them is if there is an application key generated in your '.env. file

Comment: Could it be `unknown status` because you are not returning anything from the `store` route?  Something like `return response(200)` at least might help.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything in that request.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //$drink = new Drink; //Don't know why this is here like that, so removed it
    $this->validate(request(),[
        'Name' => 'required',
        'Size' => 'required',
        'Caffeine' => 'required',
        'Url' => 'required'
    ]);

    $drink = Drink::create([
        'Name' => request('Name'),
        'Size' =>  request('Size'),
        'Caffeine' => request('Caffeine'),
        'Amount' => 0,
        'Url' => request('Url'),
        'created_at' => time(),
        'updated_at' => time(),     
    ]);
    //Maybe add the following
    return response()->json([
       'drink' => $drink,
    ]);
}
```

Let me explain you what I just did, I assign the var $drink to the creation of the new `Drink` so it return the new `Drink` model, then passed it as a json response, now you may catch it in your `success` call back

EDIT:
I made a few changes to your Angular controller, just capture all the form data in a `$scope`, put `ng-model="drink.changeThisToAnyName"` in each `input` of your form and then pass it to the ajax post as JSON, see the example:

```
$scope.answer = function() {

     $http.post('/public/drinks', {
        data: $scope.drink,
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {

     }, function myError(response) {
         console.log("error");
     }
 );
```

Comment: Just tried that, but unfortunately the same error appears.